# Double Integral: $f(x,y)=x$ if $x=y$, and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. Let $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x,y)=x$ if $x=y$, and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.
I would like to show the integral exists or not using the criterion of Riemann 
$$
\overline{\int_\Omega} f = \underline{\int_\Omega} f \text{ iff } \forall \;\epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; P_\epsilon \text{ partition of }\Omega : U(f,P_\epsilon)−L(f,P_\epsilon)< \epsilon,
$$
Other difficulty is to write the partition depending on epsilon. 
 some help?

Comment: Since the set of points on which $f(x,y) \neq 0$ is a set of measure $0$, the integral is  equal to $0$. Set your partition up, e.g., to include $\epsilon$ neighborhoods of points centered on $x=y$...

Comment: The integral exists, because it is continuous except on a set of content zero. One way to show that the integral exists is by partitioning the region of integration such that the subset determined by x=y is contained in rectangles the sum of whose areas is less than any given epsilon.

Comment: Thank you. Now my difficulty is to write the partition depending on epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying that 
$$
\frac{1}{n} < \min \{ \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}},\frac{\epsilon}{3} \}.
$$
Let a partition $P=(\{0,\frac{1}{n},\dotsc,\frac{n-1}{n},1\},\{0,\frac{1}{n},\dotsc,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}\}$ of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.
So
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
U(f,P)-L(f,P)=3.\frac{1}{n^2}.\frac{1}{n}(1+\dotsc+n-1)+\frac{1}{n^2} \\
= 3.\frac{1}{n^2}.\frac{1}{n}.\frac{(n-1).n}{2}+\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{3}{2n} + \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \; .
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Else $\int_\Omega f = \underline{\int_\Omega} f = 0$.